# Android, Как можно получить информацию о том, какой день недели является начальным в системном регионе?

Tags: java, android, locale

Например, в России неделя начинается с понедельника, в США с воскресенья и т.д.
Я нигде про это ничего не нашёл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java Date/Time API есть класс [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html), содержащий среди прочего информацию о первом дне недели, которую можно получить при помощи метода [`getFirstDayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#getFirstDayOfWeek--).

Соответственно, получить экземпляр этого класса можно при помощи метода [`WeekFields::of(Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#of-java.util.Locale-), а системную локаль можно получить при помощи метода [`Locale.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--).

Аналогично, в устаревшем классе `Calendar` есть подобный метод [`Calendar::getFirstDayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek--), возвращающий целочисленную константу (1 - воскресенье (!), ... 7 - суббота).

Пример кода:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

var locales = Arrays.asList(
    Locale.getDefault(),
    new Locale("ru", "RU"),
    new Locale("fr", "FR"),
    new Locale("ar", "DZ")
);

for(Locale loc : locales) {
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(loc).getFirstDayOfWeek();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(loc);
    System.out.println(loc.getDisplayCountry() + "\t-> first day: " + firstDayOfWeek 
        + "\tcalendar: " + cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
}
```

Результат:

```
United States   -> first day: SUNDAY    calendar: 1
Russia  -> first day: MONDAY    calendar: 2
France  -> first day: MONDAY    calendar: 2
Algeria -> first day: SATURDAY  calendar: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Через обычный Calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int first_day_of_week_def = calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek();
```

Полноценная настройка появится в Android 14, смотрите [Regional preferences](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features#regional-preferences).

```
LocalePreferences.getFirstDayOfWeek();
```